# SEO benefit for a page title of contents with anchor links to page headings

Tags: seo, wordpress, content

In one of my Wordpress single posts, I'm planning to put a plain text list of my page sub headings (H3 tags) with anchor links that jump to the page section.

Is there any benefit or harm of doing so from an SEO point of view?

For an example, see this screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Helps both directly and Indirectly... it tells Google what sections of the page are about what and indirectly because people love to link to sections rather than entire page, for example Pro Webmasters you can link to 'ANSWERS' rather than the whole question and a zillion other answers. Consider it great for SEO and UX.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree and disagree with the comment from @Simon Hayter. The contents list is a very good feature for the user experience as it allows them to jump to content further down the page without needing to scroll all the way down, and by using ID's for all of your H3 elements they can be linked to directly using the structure `file.html#id-of-h3-element` which will allow the user to jump straight to them but having a table of contents linked to the individual sections on the same page won't really make a difference to your SEO rating as it currently stands as Google will still index the content the same based on the contents of those sections linked to by the table of contents. It can however improve your SEO to link to related content on your site, both from other pages to this one and from this one to other pages, such as having a related pages block at the bottom of the page or if something on the page is the name of another page you have making the name a link to that other page.